# Swift CoreData Model Help? (Example given)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am creating an app that has a table of "collections" of sounds called mixes. Each sound in the mix has individual sound volumes associated with them.

I am struggling figuring out a data model that would work for me, keeping in mind that extra sound packs containing extra sounds can be downloaded.

Here is a picture I drew containing the basic idea.
[image]

I started with a coredata entity for the mixes, containing an array of strings of sound locations. This worked great until I tried to implement individual volumes. I then thought a coredata entity for each sound would work, but seeing as more sounds can be downloaded, it doesnt seem fitting for coredata?
I need a little guidance on how I could achieve this and for it to be future-proof for my sound pack downloading and other expansions.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do it like this to simplify your setup. [image]

**Edit:** (I have edited the entire answer/configuration after thinking through your setup)

Actually, you can even delete the "Mixes" entity, and just go with "Mixtheme", and fetch all "mixthemes" and manually creating a list of "mixes" for the user interface, to avoid the "mixes" entity. As you wish :)

This way, you can:

Fetch all mixthemes with options:  (name/locked/unlocked/other properties you choose to add)

Fetch all mixethemes connected sounds with their properties .

You actually only need these 2 entities.

Comment: I can see where you are going with this but storing the sound in a coredata entity seems to miss the point of coredata? The only property that should be edited and stored for a sound is the volume. Hardcoding a sound entity in for each sound seems a little silly right? It doesn't help that I'm new to the whole "persistent data" thing and coredata in general.

Comment: @calebmanley You don't store the actual "Audio file" if that is what you mean by sound? The "sound" entity I have shown is just a reference to the audio. The audio should be stored and loaded from disk for best practices. (or maybe if you wanna stream (?) , the option is yours) , you can add a property to the sound entity "fileurl" and store the disk location for the sound etc.

Comment: by sound I was meaning the "sound" entity. That was my exact plan, but are you suggesting I check if it is the first launch of the app, and then add each "sound" entity to coredata?

Comment: You add the "mixes" and add each sound for the mixes if they dont exist of course. Then you can mark/unmark whatever is "locked" or not, and you can fetch everything accordingly. Update the fileurl when downloaded etc. It's basically all you need to get going.

Comment: I feel like technically 'hard coding' the "sound" entities in sort of defeats the purpose of coredata, but I'll see how it goes. Thanks for the help!